# Can't refresh data on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on top of a `TablePanelLayout`. The `DataGridView`'s data is bound on a database and using this code:

```
dgvItems.DataSource = GC.CSHR_SORepo.ToList();
```

Now, I have other methods that changes the values to the database table that the `DataGridView` references to. When that change happens, I can't refresh the values of the Grid.

I have tried `dgvItems.Refresh();` `tablePanelLayout.Refresh();`, `tablePanelLayout.RefreshEdit();`

Even refreshing the form itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: `dgvItems.DataSource = GC.CSHR_SORepo.ToList();` looks like `dgvItems` is bound to a list with a local copy of db data. any changed in db are not reflected in that list. `Refresh` method of grid, laoutPanel or form force their re-draw and not related with data binding

Comment: What can you suggest @ASh?

Comment: possible solution 1: reload data and bind it again (with the same code `dgvItems.DataSource = GC.CSHR_SORepo.ToList();`); possible solution 2: track new items and add them to datasource one by one when they are created